Do I achieve higher accuracy when using a linear model with UKF, compared to KF?
If you were using a linear model and comparing two algorithms:

Kalman Filter
Unscented Kalman Filter

The Unscented Kalman Filter are made for nonlinear models, but can be used with linear models as well.
So is there anything more you can achieve, e.g. accuracy, if you were using a linear model with Unscented Kalman Filter, comparing to using regular Kalman Filter?

For the linear dynamic model with Independent Gaussian Model for the noises, the Linear Kalman Filter is accurate and optimal.
It is the optimal linear filter of all linear filters for any white noise.
In case your noise is not Gaussian, the UKF might have some advantage.
Though probably Particle Filters will be a better choice for that case.

Thank you, But would not UKF have a faster converage to the true estimate?

I saw a video on Youtube for few years ago. The author explains why a linear kalman filter will work less better compared to a UKF, even if the model is linear.

@euraad, Could you link to this video? If the noise is Gaussian I will find this to be very strange.

I will try to find it, but I haven't. It was long time ago. I post the link when I find it.
